# How to disable Collection Cache for Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, collections, ehcache

I tried to add a lot of objects into my database via `Hibernate`. 
These are mostly new objects so I dont need any caching whatsoever.
When I looked into `Jprofiler` this occured: 
[image: Bottlenec]

The cachemode is set to `IGNORE` so no cache should be put. 
The collections on my entity are using `@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)`
For normal circumstances this is perfect. But with my `Bulk insert Operation` its pretty bad.

I cant use stateless session because too many objects are used in the hierarchy. Is there a way to disable `collection caching` for a single method or transaction?